# How to start setInterval after object initialization?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, constructor

```
function Game() {
  this.number = 0;
  const t = setInterval(() => {
      this.number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      }, 1000);

  this.checkNumber = () => {
    if (this.number > 5) {
      clearInterval(this.t);
    }
    return this.number > 5;
  }
}


const game = new Game();
console.log(game.number);
```

I do have something like this and I would like to have my number changed, however setInterval doesnt seem to be initialized after my object initialization. How could I do it without doing additional method?

Comment: In your code sample the console.log(game.number) will be executed before the interval fires the code which updates the number. Try running the console.log in an interval too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this ..

```
class Game () {
  constructor(){
   //call set interval function here
 }

  //put methods here

}
```

Or self calling function

```
(function () {
  // body
})();
```

See more @ https://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Arrow Syntax

```
(() => {
  //body
})()
```

Arrow Syntax + parameter

```
((n) => {
  //body
})()
```

Comment: I need to do this via function constructor :( (school)+

Comment: @Shakered try self executing function

Comment: @Shakered yes it can

Comment: thanks, however my variable this.number is undefined after this object initialization, do you know maybe what can I do to have it changed?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I did something like this

Answer (score 0):

```
function Game() {
  (() => {
    this.t = setInterval (() => {
      this.number = Math.floor ((Math.random () * 10) + 1);
      console.log(this.number);
      this.checkNumber();
    }, 1000);
  })();

  this.checkNumber = () => {
    if (this.number > 5) {
      clearInterval(this.t);
    }
    return this.number > 5;
  };
}


const game = new Game();
```

Did something like this and it works, thanks above